# Finding specific data form a page using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to pull data from a website using the .load function in JQuery.
However i didn't write the webpage and therefore cant just assign a specific ID to the relative tag. 
The Part of the pages html that contains the bit I'm interested in is:

```
    <div class="stats"
    <h3>Current Guide Price <span title="23,539,527">23.5m</span></h3>
```

The  tag ends far after other spans. the only thing i can find special about this specific span tag is that it is the only one within a header tag,    h3, it is also the fist span in that div tag.

How can i Retrieve the "Title" data from that page using the .load function.

if it helps the url of the page is: http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/Praesul_codex/viewitem?obj=39584

Comment: is the page hosted on your website? Keep in mind: you can't send CORS request for html.

Comment: @morgomaster You need to share more of your code for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div.stats h3 span[title]').attr('title');
```

Please keep in mind that website scraping might violate the TOS and is also prone to break as soon as there are changes in the structure of the targeted website.

Comment: Where in the load statement would that be?

Comment: Show me your "load statement" and how you are currently fetching the website content and I can show you. ;-)

Comment: I'm not currently pulling anything from the website that's the problem :p,

Comment: // $("target").load('div.stats h3 span[title]').attr('title');

Comment: but obviouslt that wont work but i was wondering if i target the url?

Comment: What's a "target" html element supposed to be? It's now getting clear that your problem is not the selector (and your question sounded like it was), but a general lack of how jQuery works. I'm not going to write the complete code for a web scraper for you, so I suggest you have a look at the jQuery documentation and make yourself familiar with the restrictions of cross-domain requests. (Hint: You're going to need some kind of server-side proxy script to get the foreign html content for you)